# Spring Boot Security PermitAll with RequestHeaderMatcher not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

After having followed a tutorial about microserves and OAuth2 in Maven Spring Boot, I got a problem. I want to exclude a request from the authentication, so unauthorized data can be gotten. This only doesn't seem to work in the way I do it. Can someone help me with this?

Tutorial I followed: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/02/13/secure-spring-microservices-with-oauth#microservices-architectures-with-spring-boot--spring-cloud

What I tried:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization"))
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .andMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/beers").permitAll();
    }
}
```

I have to authenticate when I try to do the request. How do I solve this?

spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure: 2.1.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your configuration is the same as the followings . Just removing those unnecessary duplicated `authorizeRequests()` and `and()` , which make it look more clearly :

```java
  http.requestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization"))
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .andMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/beers").permitAll();
```

It means spring security will only handle the requests if it has `Authorization` header. Otherwise ,the request will be ignored and no spring security stuff will apply to it.

So if the request has the `Authorization` header , it will then start to check the rules (i.e. those matcher things configured by `authorizeRequests()`) from the top to the bottom according to the declaration order.Once a rule is matched , the bottom rule will be ignored and will not be checked.

Since your first rule is to match every HTTP request ("/**") which makes all rules below it never execute and does not have any meaning.

On the other hand , if you want spring security totally ignore  "/beers" even its request has `Authorization` header , you should configure `WebSecurity` to ignore it :

```
 public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/beers");
}
```

Comment: the classe ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter do not implement the method configure(WebSecurity web)